# React dumb component with UI state

Tags: reactjs

I want to build a select input component with React.
The select should be dumb component as it's only a UI Component,
but it also have it's own state (Whether to show the options list, or not)

How should I manage this state?

```
return (
    const Select = (props) => {
        <div>
            <label>{placeholder}</label>
            {/*some toggle state*/ && <div>props.children</div>}
        </div>   
    }
)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not get too confused by the fact that "it's only a UI component". Anything that has an internal state should be a class.

Your code, a dropdown, is my go-to example of when you should use internal state.

Manage your state with `setState()`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, what you are rendering is a `stateless component`, so it will not have any state.

What you can do is pass the `state` from the parent to this component like so:

```
constructor(props) {
  this.state = { showDumbComponent:true }
}

render() {
  <DumbComponent show={this.state.showDumbComponent} />
}
```

Comment: This component should manage it's own state about showing the list of the options.. But it's still dumb component

Answer (score 0):

Now your component is stateless, but you need a stateful.

For example:

```
class Select extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: '', toggle: false};
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <div>
        <label>{placeholder}</label>
        {this.state.toggle && <div>this.props.children</div>}
       </div>   
    );
  }
}
```

And you should change state with `setState` function.

For more information, check this [article](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Comment: Are you sure what I need is stateful component? because my component suits the definition of stateless component

Comment: If you need that your component have a it's own local state, than you need to have stateful component.